# Eclipse “Install new Software” dialog not showing

Tags: java, eclipse, dialog, installation, show

In eclipse, when i go to `Help` and click on `Install New Software` nothing seems to happen, no dialog is shown. I tried clicking several times nothing is happening. Has anyone had similar problems i'm having with eclipse IDE. Eclipse version is `IDE for Java EE Developers, luna x64`

Comment: My first question would be, what version of the JRE/JDK are you using?

Comment: @joshmcod  jdk1.8.0_31 and jre1.8.0_31

Comment: Okay. I was looking through the documentation and saw that at a minimum Java 7 was required for many of the package downloads. Just thought I'd check.

Comment: I reinstalled it, downloaded new copy and extracted in program files directory where my java folder is and now it is working.